# how to use Boost.asio for the multicast sender?

Tags: c++, windows-xp, boost-asio, multicast, sender

I'm trying to use boost.asio to implement a multicast sender. I have  a my thread implementation and I need my boost.asio only for management of the socket.

I looked at the example on the site of boost but I did not understand and I do not
Compile. Where can I find what I need?

The complile errors are:
(I have tried this example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/sender.cpp)

> Error 3   error C2653: 'asio' : is not a
>   class or namespace name   c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    2
>
> Error 4   error C2653: 'asio' : is not a
>   class or namespace name   c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    24
>
> Error 5   error C2143: syntax error :
>   missing ')' before '&'    c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    24
>
> Error 6   error C2143: syntax error :
>   missing ';' before '&'    c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    24
>
> Error 7   error C2460:
>   'sender::io_service' : uses 'sender',
>   which is being defined    c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    24
>
> Error 8   error C4430: missing type
>   specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support
>   default-int   c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    24
>
> Error 9   error C2653: 'asio' : is not a
>   class or namespace name   c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    24
>
> Error 10  error C2143: syntax error :
>   missing ';' before '&'    c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    24
>
> Error 11  error C4430: missing type
>   specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support
>   default-int   c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    24
>
> Error 13  error C2059: syntax error :
>   ')'   c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    24
>
> Error 14  error C2065:
>   'multicast_address' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    26
>
> Error 15  error C3861: 'endpoint_':
>   identifier not found  c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    26
>
> Error 16  error C2531:
>   'sender::multicast_address' :
>   reference to a bit field
>   illegal   c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    26
>
> Error 17  error C4430: missing type
>   specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support
>   default-int   c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    26
>
> Error 18  error C2327:
>   'sender::io_service' : is not a type
>   name, static, or
>   enumerator    c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    27
>
> Error 19  error C2061: syntax error :
>   identifier 'io_service'   c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    27
>
> Error 20  error C2059: syntax error :
>   ')'   c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    27
>
> Error 21  error C2061: syntax error :
>   identifier 'timer_'   c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    28
>
> Error 22  error C2143: syntax error :
>   missing ')' before '{'    c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    30
>
> Error 23  error C4430: missing type
>   specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support
>   default-int   c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    30
>
> Error 24  error C2143: syntax error :
>   missing ';' before '{'    c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    39
>
> Error 25  error C2334: unexpected
>   token(s) preceding '{'; skipping
>   apparent function body    c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    39
>
> Error 26  fatal error C1004: unexpected
>   end-of-file found c:\Documents and
>   Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp    100

Comment: Why could not you compile it?  What error messages did you get?

Comment: i have try to compile the sender.cpp (multicast)
i have this error:

Error 1 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'asio.hpp': No such file or directory 
if i change the include whith:

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
i have 23 error:


Error 3 error C2653: 'asio' : is not a class or namespace name c:\Documents and Settings\Gianluigi\Desktop\sender.cpp 24
Error 4 error C2653: 'asio' : is not a class or namespace name c:\Documents and Settings\Gianluigi\Desktop\sender.cpp 24
etc...

Comment: You should post your entire example code. Did you copy the entire file? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/sender.cpp

Comment: @GgSalent edit your question with the compile error, it is difficult to read as a comment.

Comment: @Sam i have edited my post with the compile errors.. can you help me?

Comment: @GgSalent I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/sender.cpp) you have chosen to compile should build cleanly assuming you have boost installed correctly. I don't know how your development environment is setup. On my system I have boost installed in `/opt/local` so the headers are in `/opt/local/include` and the libraries to link against are in `/opt/local/lib`. My compile and link line looks like

```
stackoverflow samm$ g++ sender.cpp  -I /opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_system -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/lib
```

The first error you see

> Error 3 error C2653: 'asio' : is not a
>   class or namespace name c:\Documents
>   and Settings\GG\Desktop\sender.cpp 2

looks like you forgot to `#include <boost/asio.hpp>` somewhere. But I am far from a Windows development expert, so perhaps someone more knowledgeable will answer.